# Grid example with custom dropdownlist in cell - how does it render a dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Im trying to transition from an editor template that was used to show a pre-defined list of items in a dropdownlist on a grid row.  This works, but I need the list customized for different grids, as the data is not the same between different areas of my application.

So Im looking at client templates and defining my own in some fashion.

In this example, Im not sure where the "categories" list is used in the view.
  Is this even used in this example?
How does a dropdownlist get rendered in the row as a result of having a "nested" property that is a list?

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom

```
private void PopulateCategories()
{
    var dataContext = new SampleEntities();
    var categories = dataContext.Categories
                .Select(c => new CategoryViewModel {
                    CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                    CategoryName = c.CategoryName
                })
                .OrderBy(e => e.CategoryName);

    ViewData["categories"] = categories;
    ViewData["defaultCategory"] = categories.First();            
}
```

Its this line that Im wondering about:
    **ViewData["categories"] = categories;**

Why is this needed and what uses it?  I see no use of it in either the controller or view - unless the read action uses this by default or convention of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewData["categories"]` is used in the editor template. This file is not displayed on the demo site, but you can see it in the offline demos that you should have from the installer:

> /Views/grid/EditorTemplates/ClientCategory.cshtml

Here is the contents:

```
@model Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CategoryViewModel

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .DataValueField("CategoryID")
    .DataTextField("CategoryName")
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"])
)
```

More information at:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/templating/editor-templates

Comment: You can also use the Grid's Foreign Key column capability if you don't want to create an EditorTemplate: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn.